# Does FME support block-comments via a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: fme-form, shortcuts

Is there a way to comment out entire blocks of code in FME with a keyboard shortcut?

All [keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Workbench/Workbench/Workbench_Keyboard_Shortcuts.htm) I could find were not related to scripting windows (like the PythonCaller-transformer) in FME.

Comment: What sort of scripts are you trying to edit in FME? Presumably, you're not looking to add comments to the FMW file itself? Are you talking about the workspace canvas or one of the text editor dialogs?

Comment: I'm talking about the text edit dialogues from the Python transformers, and the Python startup and shutdown scripting dialogues

Comment: via PyCharm? [Ctrl+Shift+/ ] https://community.safe.com/s/article/use-pycharm-as-fmeobjects-python-ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible yet. There are two workarounds:

1. Copy code from FME to IDE, which can do block comments (such as PyCharm, Visual Studio Code, Notepad ++, Spyder, etc.), do block comment via keyboard shortcut in that IDE and copy code back to FME.
2. Manually comment out each line of code in FME by putting # before.

To make commenting of a block of code in FME easier in the future, vote for this idea:
https://community.safe.com/s/bridea/a0r4Q00000JCAcdQAH/comment-out-block-of-code-in-fme-via-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: Thanks for posting. I just heard back from our developer at Safe who said the same about using an external IDE. He also suggested using the triple quotes idea, but I did read that can cause problems (Python in general, not just FME) so use that one with caution.